# Injection of autowired dependencies failed, Could not autowire field

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I know this question has been asked a lot and I am risking a double (or triple or quadruple) topic, but the proposed solutions don't seem to work for me.

I'm having trouble with the much dreaded cannot autowire error. First time setting up a complete Spring project from scratch, so I don't really know what the problem is.

This is my current setup:
ProjectRepo:

```
package be.italent.repo;

import be.italent.model.Project;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProjectRepo extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer> {

}
```

ProjectService:

```
package be.italent.services;

import be.italent.model.Project;
import be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepo projectRepo;

    public List<Project> getAllProjects() {
        return projectRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

ProjectRestController:

```
package be.italent.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import be.italent.services.ProjectService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import be.italent.model.Project;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/projects")
public class ProjectRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public ArrayList<Project> getProjects(){
        ArrayList<Project> c = (ArrayList<Project>) projectService.getAllProjects();

        return c;
    }
}
```

spring-mvc.xml

```
...
<context:component-scan base-package="be.italent"></context:component-scan>
...
```

Error:

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectRestController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private be.italent.services.ProjectService be.italent.controllers.ProjectRestController.projectService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo be.italent.services.ProjectService.projectRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private be.italent.services.ProjectService be.italent.controllers.ProjectRestController.projectService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo be.italent.services.ProjectService.projectRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>           ... 22 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo be.italent.services.ProjectService.projectRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
>           ... 24 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo be.italent.services.ProjectService.projectRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>           ... 35 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
>           ... 37 more

Any help? Thanks!

**Solution**

Added this to my spring-mvc.xml:

```
<beans
...
jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

...

<jpa:repositories base-package="be.italent.repo" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When something is wrong when initializing the application context, Spring often gives these long stack traces. Usually you can find out what the ultimate cause is by looking at the bottom of the stack trace.

In your case you see this error message at the bottom:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [be.italent.repo.ProjectRepo] found

This means that Spring cannot find a bean of type `ProjectRepo`.

Your `ProjectRepo` repository interface is in package `be.italent.repo`, which is a subpackage of `be.italent`, which is component-scanned, so the problem is not that it is in a wrong package.

Did you forget to enable Spring Data JPA?

When you use XML configuration (as you are doing now), you have to have a `repositories` XML tag in your config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <!-- Tell Spring Data JPA where your repository interfaces are -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="be.italent.repo" />

    <!-- ... -->
</beans>
```

When you use JavaConfig, you can do it with an annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("be.italent.repo")
public class MySpringConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: That did it, updating my original post!

Comment: + 100
Problem is - Spring Data provides proxy class - sub class which are CONCRETE classes during runtime for Repository interfaces. Here you have defined @Repository but not enabled the data jpa. So it could not provide a concrete proxy. 

Context cannot find a concrete impl of your repo interface and baaam - it cries out loud that it cannot find the impl - you can't instantiate interface. :)

Answer (score -2):

Problem is in the  ProjectRestController.java 
You have used @Autowired for ProjectService 
1)

1. Remove @Autowired annotation.
2. Genarate getters and setter from `projectService`.
3. Set a Bean for  `ProjectService` in spring.xml

now run your application. It works for me.

Comment: How does this change anything ? You are just writing the same code with different config. He used @Autowired. You are using the same concept in the xml !

Comment: Have you try this?...  I had the same error and tried all the way. Follow a lot of articles. But it didn't work. That's why  I used the spring.xml to inject those things. Remember you don't need to change all the @Autowired injection. You only need to is find the class and use getter setter with spring.xml.